# Should we display a user's question/answer ratio?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

What are the consequences of this? Would it provide any value? My guess is that user's would be more likely to answer questions rather than ask them if some form of reputation were involved as well.

Comment: I might be mis-remembering; there was apparently a question-to-accepted ratio, not a Q/A ratio. The latter is pretty easy to grab from the user profile.

Comment: Why would this be a good thing? I mean, why would we want to encourage people to answer rather than ask? Both asking and answering are essential to the workings of the site, and people who can answer will answer while those who have a question will ask.

Comment: And how would you solve a problem with dividing by zero? You didn't think of it, huh?

Comment: @jimmij just display the fraction. Doesn't have to be a real number

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you search thru meta for "ratio" you'll find various Q&A and proposals around all kinds of ratios. The consensus is that they all kind of don't do what ppl want and just become a distraction.

- [Should we have a policy about "too much downvoting"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42601/should-we-have-a-policy-about-too-much-downvoting)
- [Healthy ratios for asking:answering and up:down voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52315/healthy-ratios-for-askinganswering-and-updown-voting)
- [Add a question/answer ratio below the % accepted stats on questions for the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90741/add-a-question-answer-ratio-below-the-accepted-stats-on-questions-for-the-aske)

I can go on but basically from what I've seen around this is that ratios can be found out using the [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) if you're really interested in finding out things like this but in general the opinion of Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky and others have come to the conclusion that ratios don't really offer anything positive to the site.

This was part of the reason that they removed the ratio of accepted answers from the UI a few years ago as case in point.

- [Is having a 'bad' accept ratio necessarily a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73250/is-having-a-bad-accept-ratio-necessarily-a-bad-thing)
- [Let's stop displaying a user's accept rate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate)

That last link is the proposal to remove the accepted answer ratio BTW.